# JTable with axis

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I'm fiddling around with JTable, and I want to make a table which has the letters A-P as row names, and the number 1-24 as column names (it doesn't matter what data type they are). It does not matter if these row and column names are inside the table or as an external axis (whatever is simpler).

My current attempt is to name a `String[]` for row and column names, and a `String[][]` with the actual content. But I can't find out how to merge this into a valid format for creating a JTable. My current code (that does not work) is as following:

```
    // Create table
    String[] columnNames = {"", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
                              "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
                             };

    String[] rowNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"};

    String[][] compoundNames = new String[25][16];

    Object[][] plateData = {rowNames, compoundNames};

    table = new JTable(plateData, columnNames);
    table.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    table.setBounds(10, 11, 564, 440);
    contentPane.add(table);
```

Suggested solutions does not have to follow this concept thought. As said, the simplest possible way to make what I need, would be much appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't matter what data type they are). It does not matter if these row and column names are inside the table or as an external axis (whatever is simpler). == loop inside 1st column (only) and then to setValueAt for rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `String[][] compoundNames = new String[25][16];` should be `String[][] compoundNames = new String[16][25];` (No. elements for `columnName`s and `rowNames`)
- for basic informations is required to read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TableWithTimer {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable myTable;
    private String[] columnNames = {"", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",
        "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"};
    private String[] rowNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    private Object[][] compoundNames = new String[26][25];
    private int count = 1;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;

    public TableWithTimer() {
        myTable = new JTable(compoundNames, columnNames);
        myTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        myTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        myTable.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
        myTable.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        scroll.setViewportView(myTable);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(2500, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("updating row " + (count + 1));
                TableModel model = myTable.getModel();
                int row = model.getRowCount() - 1;// -1 == leave the cell empty at [0, 0]
                for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                    myTable.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
                    Object value = rowNames[j];
                    model.setValueAt(value, count, 0);
                    count++;
                    if (count >= myTable.getRowCount()) {
                        myTable.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
                        timer.stop();
                        System.out.println("update cycle completed");
                        myTable.clearSelection();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                //System.out.println(info.getName());
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        TableWithTimer tableWithTimer = new TableWithTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Row Header for the alphabetic values. Here is an example that uses a row header:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableRowHeader extends JList implements TableModelListener
{
    private JTable table;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TableRowHeader(JTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;

        setAutoscrolls( false );
        setCellRenderer(new RowHeaderRenderer());
        setFixedCellHeight(table.getRowHeight());
        setFixedCellWidth(50);
        setFocusable( false );
        setModel( new TableListModel() );
        setOpaque( false );
        setSelectionModel( table.getSelectionModel() );
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener( this );
    }

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.INSERT
        ||  e.getType() == TableModelEvent.DELETE)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Use the table to implement the ListModel
     */
    class TableListModel extends AbstractListModel
    {
        public int getSize()
        {
            return table.getRowCount();
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index)
        {
            return String.valueOf(index + 1);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Use the table row header properties to render each cell
     */
    class RowHeaderRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
    {
        RowHeaderRenderer()
        {
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            setOpaque(true);
            setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());
            setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
        }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {

            if (isSelected)
            {
                setBackground( table.getSelectionBackground() );
            }
            else
            {
                setBackground( table.getTableHeader().getBackground() );
            }

            setText( (value == null) ? "" : value.toString() );

            return this;
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {

        final JTable table = new JTable( 1000, 256 );
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView( new TableRowHeader( table) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Row Header Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your case you will not need the custom ListModel. You can just add the values A-P to the JList.